# Console streaming client for icecast

Tags: icecast

I need a console streaming client for [icecast](http://www.icecast.org/) which allows me to use dynamic playlists and can play mp3.
Ices2 support dynamic playlists but it plays ogg only, it does not support mp3 files.

Answer (score 0):

The only client that comes to mind is [**Ices0**](http://www.icecast.org/ices.php) the predecessor of Ices2.

Unfortunately Ices0 was deprecated at version 0.4. After Medibuntu also stopped their service there is no repository and there may be no DEBIAN package available for Ices0. You will have to compile from source.

Because of it's deprecated state there will be no way to predict it's behaviour with future  releases of Icecast2. I could not test on a present release but I was able to run Ices0 fine in previous version on Ubuntu 12.04 and earlier.

Ices0 source comes with a good documentation, and we are quite versatile with palylists, as it supports playlist handling via custom Perl or Python plugins.